# Do predicates concatenated in multiple brackets behave the same as the and operator?

Tags: xpath, predicate

I'm writing a [DOM selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/) to xpath converter and it just so happens that it would suit me very much if I could concatenate multiple predicates like this:

```
//div[@id][@class]
```

instead of like this:

```
//div[@id and @class]
```

Although a cursory test appears to suggest they behave the same, I'm not entirely sure they will under all circumstances. Will they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using multiple predicates is 100% equivalent to using the `and` operator *provided that neither predicate is positional*. A positional predicate is one whose value is numeric, or that explicitly uses `position()` or `last()`. For example, `*[@x][1]` is not the same as `*[1][@x]`.